# zref: some properties are not obtainable when they are added in my own property list

Tags: zref

I'd like to create a single label in `ref` containing multiple values (page, counter, position...). I'm not sure why, but using `zref` I can't manage to get access to the `counter` value, the `zposx` value... Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{zref-savepos,zref-abspage,zref-user,zref-counter,zref-abspos,zref-pagelayout}
\makeatletter
%% Create a list of properties to register for our labels (by default labels only ship with a subset of properties)
%% See https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/zref/zref.pdf, "Declared properties" page 10
\zref@newlist{subproof}
\zref@addprops{subproof}{abspage,posx,posy,counter,pagevalue,paperwidth} % <- Any solution to just add "main,savepos,thepage..."

\NewDocumentCommand\subproofMarkStart{m}{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{subproof}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\subproofMarkStop{m}{%
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{subproof}%
}

\makeatother
\author{}


\begin{document}

Hello \subproofMarkStart{blibli}

\zref[abspage]{blibli}

The counter of blibli is \zref[counter]{blibli} (why is it empty?), the position is \zposx{blibli} (why??)
The paper width is \zref[paperwidth]{blibli}

I would expect to see a line drawn:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw (current page.north west) -- ([xshift=\zposx{blibli}sp,yshift=\zposy{blibli}sp]current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `\zref@savepos\zref@labelbylist{#1}{subproof}` for the position. And counter can only store something if a counter has been set before.

Comment: Thanks! But how am I supposed to set the counter? Should I redefine `\@currentcounter` manually before the call to labelbylist?

Comment: why should you set it? The property is there to tell you if and which counter has been set. If it is empty it means you didn't change a counter yet. If you add e.g. \section{blub} this will change.

Comment: Ah ok, then I misunderstood it's usage,I thought it was made to count the number of labels that were defined. I guess I need my own prop then. Btw, I also wanted to ask: is it possible to use zref to maintain the list of all label names that were defined in the file, or should I manually write in the aux file? I basically want to loop over all labels of a certain kind.